# bash: executing an output of a script as a script

Tags: bash

I'm writing a simple script to generate all combinations of a and b of a given length (say 10). I want to be able to do this on a command line (I know this is fairly easy if I just put everything in a bash script file and execute it). However, I was wondering if it's possible to do without any extra files. Here's what I have so far:

```
n=10;
for i in `seq 1 1 $n`; do
    echo "for a$i in {a..b}; do ";
done;
echo -n "echo ";
for i in `seq 1 1 $n`; do
    echo -n '$'"a$i"; done;
    echo;
for i in `seq 1 1 $n`; do
    echo "done;";
done
```

(I formatted the code for readability, but it's actually all on one line run from a prompt)

This gives me the following output:

```
for a1 in {a..b}; do 
for a2 in {a..b}; do 
for a3 in {a..b}; do 
for a4 in {a..b}; do 
for a5 in {a..b}; do 
for a6 in {a..b}; do 
for a7 in {a..b}; do 
for a8 in {a..b}; do 
for a9 in {a..b}; do 
for a10 in {a..b}; do 
echo $a1$a2$a3$a4$a5$a6$a7$a8$a9$a10
done;
done;
done;
done;
done;
done;
done;
done;
done;
done;
```

which is just fine. If I copy that and paste it back on the command line, it works like a charm and gives me the result.

The question is how do I do this with just the initial script, without copy-pasting and without redirecting anything to files.

I've tried sticking $( ) around the script, but that gives me "No command 'for' found'", since it's not really a command but a bash builtin. I've tried putting eval somewhere before this, but I just keep getting more errors. I'm a bit stuck, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Btw, just to reiterate, I'm doing this more or less to just learn bash more -- that's why I don't want to redirect the output to a file and then execute that file. I know how to do that part, but I don't know how to just do it from command line)

Comment: `n=10; str=; for ((i=0; i < $n; ++i)); do str+='{a..b}'; done; eval echo $str`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use an eval, $() gives you a string.

```
eval $( echo echo foo )
```

Another option is to stick into a subshell and pipe it to a bash:

```
(echo echo foo) | /bin/bash
```

Comment: here's what I get:

user@host:/tmp$ eval $( n=10; for i in `seq 1 1 $n`; do echo "for a$i in {a..b}; do "; done; echo -n "echo "; for i in `seq 1 1 $n`; do echo -n '$'"a$i"; done; echo; for i in `seq 1 1 $n`; do echo "done;"; done )
bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Maybe I have to escape some $ or quotes?

Comment: sweet, the pipe to /bin/bash worked. I tried it before without brackets around the script and it didn't. I learned something today. :D (I'll accept as soon as it will let me)

Comment: Do realize though that you're now using three shell processes, the first is the one executing the `() | sh`, the second is the one executing the code in the subshell and the last is the one executing the output of the subshell. See `echo $BASHPID ; ( echo echo $BASHPID ; echo echo \$BASHPID ) | /bin/bash`

Answer (score 2):

You can do `for i in $(seq $n)` instead of `seq 1 1 $n`.

You can do `for ((i=1; i<=$n; i++))` and avoid calling an external utility.

You can do this (slightly hacky with ***only one loop***):

```
$ a=A; b=B; n=4; s=''; for ((i=1;i<=n;i++)); do s+="{$a..$b}"; done; eval echo "''" $s"$'\n'"
```

or this (highly hacky ***without any loops***):

```
$ a=A; b=B; n=4; eval echo "''" $(printf "{$a..$b}%.0s" $(eval echo "{1..$n}"))"$'\n'"
```

Either one will get you this:

```
 AAAA
 AAAB
 AABA
 AABB
 ABAA
 ABAB
 ABBA
 ABBB
 BAAA
 BAAB
 BABA
 BABB
 BBAA
 BBAB
 BBBA
 BBBB
```