# Double sequence with brackets?

Tags: bash, brackets

I was wondering if there is a simple way to produce a double sequence with something similar to curl braces.

I would like to produce a double sequence like this one:

```
eog directory1/somethingelse/file2.png  directory3/somethingelse/file6.png ...  directory25/somethingelse/file50.png
```

The sequences of directories and files are regular (I mean is something like, e.g., {1..25..2} for directories and {2..50..4} for files).

I wonder if there is a simple way to produce the sequences instead of using vectors with all the values. I mean something like

```
eog directory[someOpenedBracket]1..25..2[someClosedBracket]/somethingelse/file[someOpenedBracket]2..50..4[someClosedBracket].png
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your goal? `echo directory{1..25..2}/somethingelse/file{2..50..4} | wc -w` answer: `169` ( *`13 x 13 = 169`* It's ok for me)?!

Comment: Need a clarification if you need `directory1/somethingelse/file2.png`, you don't need `directory1/somethingelse/file6.png` from the same folder?

Comment: I need directory1/somethingelse/file2.png  directory3/somethingelse/file6.png ...  directory25/somethingelse/file50.png where the individual sequencies of directories and files are known and are, e.g., {1..25..2} and {2..50..4}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate 2 separate array and loop through them:

```
dirs=(directory{1..25..2})
files=(file{2..50..4})

for ((i=0; i<${#dirs[@]}; i++)); do
    printf '%s ' "${dirs[i]}/somethingelse/${files[i]}.png"
done
echo
```

**Output:** (appears in one line in output)

```
directory1/somethingelse/file2.png
directory3/somethingelse/file6.png
directory5/somethingelse/file10.png
directory7/somethingelse/file14.png
directory9/somethingelse/file18.png
directory11/somethingelse/file22.png
directory13/somethingelse/file26.png
directory15/somethingelse/file30.png
directory17/somethingelse/file34.png
directory19/somethingelse/file38.png
directory21/somethingelse/file42.png
directory23/somethingelse/file46.png
directory25/somethingelse/file50.png
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution is almost perfect, I just need to print everything in the same line, so I only made a little modification to your solution changing the echo line like this: echo -n "${dirs[i]}/somethingelse/${files[i]}.png" adding a space between " and $

Comment: And of course I added a line containing "echo -n eog" before the for loop

Comment: Using the results of this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017578/bash-executing-an-output-of-a-script-as-a-script completes all the story.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is all you can achieve with Bash.

```
eog $(i=0; while ((++i<=25)); do echo dir$i/file$((i++*2)); done)
```

Comment: Thanks. In general the sequence is not so regular, but I will figure out the problem case by case.